# Linear map between $V \otimes W $ and $ \mathcal{L}(V^*,W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, dual-spaces

I've proved by universal property that there exists $\Gamma: V \otimes W \to \mathcal{L}(V^{*},W)$ given by $$\Gamma(v \otimes w)(f)= f(v)w.$$

My question is, $\Gamma$ is injective? If $v \otimes w \in \ker \Gamma$, then $\Gamma(v \otimes w )(f) = 0$ for all $f \in V^{*}$. I mean, how can I proof that it implies $v\otimes w = 0?$

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional a basic argument suffices for proving that the given map is an isomorphism (which implies injectivity); I don't know if the injectivity holds in general.

Comment: It is, but I don't have the hipotesys about dimension...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on mrtaurho's comment, the basic argument for FDVS is actually that this map is injective and then add the fact that it's finite dimensional so it's an isomorphism. Here's how you see it's injective.

If $\Gamma(v \otimes w)(f) = f(v)w = 0$ for all $f$, then either $w = 0$ or $f(v) = 0$ for all $f$. The former immediately implies that $v \otimes w = 0$, and as for the latter, since $f(v) = 0$ for all $f$, this is only true if $v = 0$ (why is this?), so again we have $v \otimes w = 0$. So the kernel is trivial, and the map is injective.

Comment: I was thinking about that... $v \otimes w = 0 \iff v =0$ or $w=0$??

Comment: You have an implication in one direction but not necessarily the other. If $v = 0$ then certainly $v \otimes w = 0$. However you can have non-zero vectors whose tensor product is zero.

Comment: Actually, I think as long as you are working over a field (which I presume you are since), you can say that $v \otimes w = 0 \iff v = 0$ or $w = 0$. It's tensor products of modules where things start to go wrong.

Comment: That only shows injectivity when restricted to generators $v \otimes w$ of $V \otimes W$.  What about sums $\sum_{i=1}^r v_i \otimes w_i$ of these generators?

Comment: Oops right! Well the extension is easy. If you have a sum of such generators, you can rewrite the sum so that the $w_j$ are linearly independent (use the dependence relations along with bilinearity)  so you have a sum $\sum f(v_j)w_j = 0$. By linear independence, $f(v_j) = 0$ for all $f$ so $v_j = 0$ and each summand is $0$. Having written it out though, this is more of a different answer than an extension really.